# How to GROUP BY a string part in MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, group-by

EDIT:

Assuming you've got the following table:

```
id  string         number
1   stuff::a::312  5 
2   stuff:::a::312 6
3   stuff::a::233  2
4   stuff:b::213   1
5   stuff::b::222  1
6   stuff::c       5
```

The following doesn't work of course:

```
SELECT string, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
-- WHERE
GROUP BY string;
```

The wished result:

```
string numbers
a      13
b      2
c      5
```

Sorry, but please note that after c is no :: but before, just like the rest

Comment: You can also use `LEFT(string,10)` if the characters `stuff::?::` in front is the standard format/length of values in your string column. `RIGHT(string,3)` is the vice versa :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the pattern is same you can do something as

```
select 
substring_index(string,'::',1) as string_val,
sum(number) as number
from mytable
group by string_val
```

Comment: This works like a charm! Since I added the "suff::a::" the substring_index(string, '::',2) is the right answer for my case. Thanks!

Comment: Well if the pattern is changed as in your question then you need something as `substring_index(substring_index(string,'::',2),'::',-1)`

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with SUBSTRING_INDEX() like this:

```
SELECT string, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
-- WHERE
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, '::', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
select substr(string,1,1)
     , count(*)
  from tbl
 group by 1
     ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use substr for this:

```
SELECT substr(string,1, 1), COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
-- WHERE
GROUP BY substr(string,1, 1);
```

Or more sophisticated SUBSTRING_INDEX:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, '::', 1), COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
-- WHERE
GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(string, '::', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select left(string,1),count(*) from table where string is not null group by left(string,1) order by left(string,1)
```

I hope this helps,
LEFT(string) will only take left most character

Comment: This actually works if i count the characters from the left, thanks. But any idea if the number of chars from the left is unknown?