# Laravel eloquent: GroupBy EMPLOYEE then DAY

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am building a Web app with Laravel (6.3)

I have a table `appointments` which following columns

- id
- startDateTime
- endDateTime
- employee_id
- client_id

I want to get results grouped by employees, then inside employees grouped by DAY like this:

```
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "Angela" => array:6 [▼
        "2020-05-25" => array:2 [▼
            0 => array:6 [▼
              "employee_id" => 6
              "appointmentId" => 566
              "startDateTime" => "2020-05-25 08:00:00"
              "endDateTime" => "2020-05-25 09:00:00"
              "employee" => "Angela"
              "img_slug" => "salon-adam_angela.jpg"
            ]
            1 => array:6 [▼
              "employee_id" => 6
              "appointmentId" => 567
              "startDateTime" => "2020-05-25 09:00:00"
              "endDateTime" => "2020-05-25 10:30:00"
              "employee" => "Angela"
              "img_slug" => "salon-adam_angela.jpg"
            ]
        ]
        "2020-05-26" => array:3 
        "2020-05-27" => array:2
        "2020-05-28" => array:4
        "2020-05-29" => array:2
        "2020-05-30" => array:1
    ]
    "Stefanie" => array:6
    "Karolina" => array:6
    "Martina" => array:6
    "Ivonne" => array:1
  ]
]
```

I am using Laravel, so my eloquent query looks like this

```
Appointment::where('appointments.employee_id', $employeeId)
    ->join('employees', 'employees.id', 'appointments.employee_id')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', 'employees.user_id')
    ->orderBy('appointments.startDateTime')
    ->select(
        'employees.id as employee_id',
        'appointments.id as appointmentId', 'appointments.startDateTime', 'appointments.endDateTime',
        'users.first_name as employee'
    )                     
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('employee')
    ->groupBy('appointments.startDateTime')
    ->toArray();
```

However it just groups by employee, but ignores the day.

If I eliminate the `->groupBy('appointments.startDateTime')` I get all the appointments correctly grouped by employee, but when I add the second grouping it just get two levels deeper array, but not grouped by dates.

I have tried all known combinations without success

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to group by a datetime, not a date.

You need to `left` or `substr` your datetime into a date so you can then group by it. [Here's an example of how to do it in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36763967/6632744)

Add `->addSelect(DB::raw("left(appointments.startDateTime, 10) as startDate"))` onto your query builder (or alternatively include the `DB::raw` and its contents in your current `->select()`).

Then change your group bys to be `->groupBy(['employee', 'startDate'])`, and you should be golden.

Comment: it gives exactly the same results: Each employee with all his appointments all together. I am trying to organize appointments per day inside each employee

Comment: Stick the two into one `groupBy`. `->groupBy(["employee", "startDate"])`

Comment: Sweet, I updated my answer to match. I'd just forgotten how two `groupBy()`s interacted on the same `Builder`.